# Module async not found

Tags: node.js

I'm studying node.js
and I am making the exercises from a book
https://github.com/marcwan/LearningNodeJS/blob/master/Chapter05/05_series.js

I have a problem with an example in which you invoke the module async.js
when I go to run the example I get the error
"can not find module 'async'"

in the folder where you installed node
I checked that there is a module
I also downloaded this package
https://github.com/caolan/async

and launched the test file that works properly

the first question that you do, even if it seems correctly installed the module, there is a command to verify that a module is installed and that you can recall?

the second question is, why is this wrong example?

thanks

Comment: You should be using `npm`, not downloading packages from github manually: `npm install async`

Comment: I uninstalled the module, canceled the download folder and install the new module with the command:
npm install async
under the command I get the answer
async@1.2.1 async

the command I run in the root of node,

then I go to the folder where the examples I launch the file node 05_series.js but I still get the error can not find module async

Comment: The `node_modules` directory that you install it into (which will be a subdirectory of the directory you are in when you run the install command), must be in the directory where you script is, or an ancestor of that directory ( see: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders ).

Comment: `npm` is generally a per project package manager, so it doesn't hurt to install several copies of `async` on your system. Once per node.js project. For instance, you could run `npm install async` in your examples folder, and then you have that dependency available inside that folder and it's subdirectories, but nowhere else on your system.

Comment: thanks @Paulpro, I installed async I downloaded directly in the examples folder and working properly, if you write an answer and not as a comment I'll vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using npm, not downloading packages from github manually: `npm install async`.

npm will install the module into a `node_modules` subdirectory of the directory that you run it in. That directory must be your examples folder, or an ancestor. See: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Answer (score 1):

To install a package, use `npm install package_name`.

When that's done, you can easily require that package and use it in your application.

`const package = require('package_name');`

To install a package globally (so you don't have to install it in every project you create) add `-g` flag

`npm install package_name -g`